# How to Split value in Jmeter from Response?

Tags: java, json, regex, jmeter

I am new to JMeter. I want to extract and Split response.
Here is the response,

```
{
   "totalDocs":3,
   "recordBatchSize":10,
   "listingType":1,
   "currentPageNo":1,
   "recordStartFrom":0,
   "data":[
      {
         "fileType":"filetype/pdf.gif",
         "issueNo":1,
         "revisionId":"123456$$kWGFhP",
      },
      {
         "fileType":"filetype/pdf.gif",
         "issueNo":1,
         "revisionId":"222222$$kFMFhP",
      },
      {
         "fileType":"filetype/pdf.gif",
         "issueNo":1,
         "revisionId":"333333$$kYEGhP",
      }
   ],
   "viewType":"listing",
   "sortFieldType":"timestamp",
   "isIncludeSubFolder":true,
   "totalListData":0
}
```

I want to extract **revisionId** and split numbers i.e 123456, 222222, 333333

Also please share where in JMeter I extract this value? **Using Regular Expression Extractor Or JSR223 Post Processor, I am new to both.**

I've tried with `"revisionId"\s*:\s*"(\d+)` (Which **@Dmitri T** suggested) but it passes variable name in the request i.e ${ref_paramrevisionId1}. see attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest would be going for the Regular Expression Extractor, the following regular expression should extract the numbers you're looking for:

```
"revisionId"\s*:\s*"(\d+)
```

Explanation:

- `\s*` - matches an arbitrary number of whitespaces
- `\d+` - matches an arbitrary number of digits

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter-Using-RegEx-(Regular-Expression-Extractor)-with-JMeter)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Thanks but How can I get the revisionID of specific index. i.e 2nd revisionID 222222. What to add in this expression "revisionId"\s*:\s*"(\d+)